# How Can I have Exposed filter for Taxonomy vocabulary in Heirarchical Select?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I use drupal 7 and [simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module for filter views module result by taxonomy terms and taxonomy vocabularies.

my views have results only if select both vocabulary and taxonomy term from select list (exposed filter) .if I select only vocabulary from select list I have no any result for views.

So i want to have a exposed filter that can filter views by vocabulary (all its taxonomy terms) and taxonomy term (sub level of vocabulary)  .
please see this picture.

Is any other way for filter views result by both vocabulary and terms in heirarchically?

[image]

thank you beforehand.

Comment: I found this solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module; in the filter fields, I selected *has taxonomy term (with dept) - simple_hierarchical-select* and set its value to 1.